# How to find minimum of a tuples list

Tags: ocaml

I have to find a minimum of a tuples list but I only want to return the minimum of `snd` element of the tuples, not the entire tuple. Unfortunately i'm having the following error in the following code and I don't know why. The l argument is a list of tuples `(float * float)`

```
let rec minRight l = match l with
    | [] -> raise (Arg.Bad "minRight: empty list")
    | [x]-> x
    | (_,y)::xs -> min y (minRight xs)
```

**Error:**

```
| (_,y)::xs -> min y (minRight xs)
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'b * 'a
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one problem, in addition to the ones mentioned in previous answers: the line

```
| [x]-> x
```

returns a tuple, while you said you want to "return the minimum of snd element[s] of the tuples".

Comment: Ok, i think that is the problem, i remove that line and finally compiles :D

Comment: Don't remove this line, the function would not handle the case of lists of length one. It would than always end up in the first case throwing an exception. Instead, rewrite it `| [_,y]-> y`. (PS: don't forget to upvote all answers that were useful).

Comment: Thanks! The solution is:

let rec minRight l = match l with
    | [] -> raise (Arg.Bad "minRight: empty list")
    | [(x,y)]-> y
    | (_,y)::xs -> min y (minRight xs)

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe your problem is that you named your function `min`, but you also want to use the standard OCaml function `min`. Is that possible?

OCaml doesn't have overloading (as compensation it has parametric polymorphism). So you need to use different names for things.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've changed the original name to "min" to simplify but i forgot that problem.. But the original function name is not min, so that's not the problem =/

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. I can't give you a vote up because of my reputation.

Comment: (May we all be able to transcend our reputations. I think the other guys helped more than I did anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

We can break this down into two separate problems. First you need to get just the second elements from each tuple. Then you need to find the minimum of *those* values.

The first parts is easy:

```
let min_right = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "Empty list."
  | lst -> lst |> List.map snd
```

Now, we can use `List.fold_left` to get the minimum. Providing the first value as the initial minimum to `List.fold_left` we only need to map over the tail of the list (which may be empty).

```
let min_right = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "Empty list."
  | (_, y)::tl -> 
    tl
    |> List.map snd
    |> List.fold_left min y
```

But if you feel that iterating over the list entirely to strip the second element from each before then iterating over the whole thing *again* to find the minimum is repetitive, future OCaml offers [sequences](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html). *As of OCaml 4.07 - July 2018.*

```
let min_right = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "Empty list."
  | (_, y)::tl -> 
    tl
    |> List.to_seq 
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.fold_left min y
```